# Two for each loop statement in workbook change event

Tags: excel, for-loop, event-handling, vba

When I try to run two for each loops in workbook change event, only second loop executing and also msgbox window repeatably pop up, not closing. How can I find a favorable solution for it? Please refer to the below code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set a = Worksheets("first").Range("q2:q417")

    ' first foreachloop
    -------------------

    For Each b In a
        If b.Value <> "" And Not IsDate(b) Then
            b.ClearContents
            MsgBox ("please enter valid date")
        End If
    Next b

    'second foreach loop
    --------------------
    Set c = Worksheets("first").Range("s2:s417")
    For Each C In a
        If C.Value <> "A" Or _
           C.Value <> "B" Or _
           C.Value <> "EF" Or _
           C.Value <> "CE" Then
            C.ClearContents
            MsgBox ("PLEASE ENTER VALID STATUS")
        End If
    Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set c = Worksheets("first").Range("s2:s417")` --> `Set a = ...`. Also an advice: use `Option Explicit` and define your variables.

Comment: You said Change Event but your code is for Selection Change Event. So each time the selection on the sheet is changed, the code will be triggered and you will get a msgbox if the criteria is met. What are you trying to achieve here with the selection change event?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you're trying to monitor the cell content of the specified ranges uppon change.

Therefore:

a) You need to change the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to `Worksheet_Change`.

b) You need to check which cell was changed, and if it's whithin the specified range, validate its content.

Place the code below to the module behind the "first" sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim a As Range
    Set a = Range("q2:q417")

    If Not Intersect(Target, a) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If Not IsEmpty(.Value) And Not IsDate(.Value) Then
                .ClearContents
                MsgBox "please enter valid date"
            End If
        End With
    End If

    Dim b As Range
    Set b = Range("s2:s417")

    If Not Intersect(Target, b) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If Not IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                If .Value <> "A" And _
                    .Value <> "B" And _
                    .Value <> "EF" And _
                    .Value <> "CE" Then
                    .ClearContents
                    MsgBox "PLEASE ENTER VALID STATUS"
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you do realize that the purpose of the `Worksheet_Change` event is to capture the events that happening usually on `Worksheets("first")`. therefore it's enough to use `Set a = Range("Q2:Q417")`. What errors are you trying to trap with `ErrProc` ?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the notes.